# Cannot Install .Net Framework 3.5 on XP

Tags: windows-xp, installation, .net-framework

I used to have Visual Studio 2008 installed on my XP Laptop. I used Add/Remove Programs to remove the program because I had some serious disk space issues. I am now trying to reinstall Visual Studio 2008 but it keeps failing and saying it cannot install .Net Framework 3.5

I have tried many different things. I have tried the installer found at [this website](https://web.archive.org/web/20160301085724/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/astebner/archive/2008/08/28/8904493.aspx).

I am at the end of the line here, I'm not finding any new information. If anyone can provide any insight, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try installing the .NET Framework separately through Windows Update. If nothing else, you can go to version 4 of the Framework which should make Visual Studio 2008 happy as well.

Comment: Looks like that worked. Too bad I spent an entire day trying to get it to work.

Thank You.